# How do I change the color of a specific GradientStop in a LinearGradientBrush in VB code behind at runtime?

Tags: wpf

I have a simple linear gradient brush in a resource that im trying to change the color of specific gradient stops in run time when an event is fired in VB code behind.

Here is the linear gradient:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TopTextBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9696" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9B9696" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Here is the Border control with the resource:

```
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" CornerRadius="2, 2, 0, 0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{DynamicResource TopTextBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
        <TextBlock Name="CaptionTB" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Caption" Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
    </Border>
```

Here is the code inside of my event that I have so far. It does not work because it says:

Cannot set a property on object '#FF9B9696,0' because it is in a read-only state.

```
Dim LGB1 = DirectCast(Me.FindResource("TopTextBackgroundBrush"), LinearGradientBrush)
LGB1.GradientStops(0).Color = New ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFFFFFFF")
```

Comment: You can't change the *resource*, but I believe you can change the *Border's* background brush directly, if you give the Border a name so it can be referenced in the code-behind.

Comment: i found this definition of static vs dynamic and still a little confused. "StaticResource will be resolved on object construction.
DynamicResource will be evaluated and resolved every time control needs the resource." why cant i, since i called it via dynamic resource, change the resource then add some code to re initialze/redraw the control containing the border so it can update to the new color?

Comment: the reason i dont want to directly edit it is because the border is in a user control that i create over 30 instances of and if i can just change the resource and redraw it would be a lot easier then writing 30+ lines of code to change the border color of each little instance of the uc each time i want to, which could be often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding SolidColorBrush to ControlTemplate Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895192/binding-solidcolorbrush-to-controltemplate-background)

Comment: `DynamicResource` doesn't let you modify the existing resource object. It needs you to _replace_ that object with an entirely new object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895192/binding-solidcolorbrush-to-controltemplate-background for an example (this question is effectively a duplicate of that one, though of course it didn't exist when you asked this one...it's unfortunate no one bothered to provide an answer three years ago).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem recently. The problem here is that LinearGradientBrush becomes frozen when used.
There is no way to unfreeze once frozen object. But you can Clone it, which makes it unfrozen copy and then you can change GradientStops color to your liking.
Like here on the example below (C# though):

```
        RulerC11B.Fill = RulerC11B.Fill.Clone();
        (RulerC11B.Fill as LinearGradientBrush).GradientStops[0].Color = someColor1;
        (RulerC11B.Fill as LinearGradientBrush).GradientStops[1].Color = someColor2;
```